# How to use picam with ctypes?

Tags: python, module, ctypes

I'm trying to write a code that interacts with a Princeton Instruments camera using Picam. Since I don't know C, I'm wrapping it in Python. I'm basing myself on PythonForPicam by Joe Lowney. The error occurs when I try to call on the file picam.dll. Here is my code:

```
import sys
#Add a path to wherever the picam package folder is located
sys.path.append(r'c:\Users\Me\Documents')

import ctypes


picam = ctypes.CDLL(r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Picam package')
```

Running this returns:

```
picam = ctypes.CDLL(r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Picam package')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-93fbba6616be>", line 1, in <module>
    picam = ctypes.CDLL(r'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Picam package')

  File "C:\Users\Me\Anaconda3\envs\PyPicam\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 
  366, in __init__
     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I don't know which module the error refers to, even when I open the **init** file and read the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck on this for four days :(

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I'm working on another script that also uses ctypes and I get the same error message as above, so the problem can't only be with the .ddl import, since my other program doesn't have that.

Comment: `ctypes.CDLL` expects a *.dll* path as an arg.

Comment: @CristiFati What do you mean by that? My .dll is in the folder specified by the path. That doesn't work?

Comment: No. You have to pass the *.dll* path (including its name). What do you think would happen if you pass a path to a dir that contains more *.dll*s?

Comment: @CristiFati It worked. Thanks!